# Trouble removing newline characters

Tags: python, string, file, formatting, text-files

I have been trying to rewrite a text file with python, where I go into a file, 
grab each line, append an additional string onto the line, then rewrite the 
newly appended line to the text file.  The problem I am having is that this 
newly constructed text file does not format correctly. The file contains 
rows, where each row contains three numbers, seperated by a comma. If my file 
looks like the following:

```
57.88, 58.45, 45.31
57.88, 58.45, 45.31
57.88, 58.45, 45.31
```

And I want to add the character "a" to the lines, then I would need the file 
to look like so:

```
57.88, 58.45, 45.31, a
57.88, 58.45, 45.31, a
57.88, 58.45, 45.31, a
```

Instead, the file formats like this (when I open it in both emacs and gedit)

```
57.88, 58.45, 45.31
,a
57.88, 58.45, 45.31
,a
57.88, 58.45, 45,31
,a
```

Interestingly, the number of lines is still the same (3) regardless of the format
of the file.  I am really confused and somewhat frustrated about this.  Below is 
the code I am using to rewrite the file.  My python skills are really picked up as 
needed, so it may be there is some obvious python function I need to use that I 
have not heard of.  Basically, once I determine the filepath exists, I call a 
rewrite subroutine, given below:

```
def getLines(filePath):
    move(filePath, filePath+"~")
    destination = open(filePath, "w")
    source = open(filePath+"~", "r")
    for line in source:
            destination.write(line.strip("\n") + ",a\n"))
    source.close()
    destination.close()
```

Comment: I reformatted some of your text.  Let me know if I did it wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You're correctly removing the final `\n` of each line before adding the `,a\n`. Are you sure you're looking at the correct files?

Comment: @DJV -- OP is using *different* files.

Comment: Maybe there are carriage returns instead of newlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try being less explicit and letting strip do the work for a cross platform solution

```
...
for line in source:
    destination.write(line.strip() + ",a\n"))
```

Alternatively try this,

```
for line in source.readlines()
    destination.write(line + ",a\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a non Unix platform, it is possible that your file contains `\r\n` line terminators. Try right stripping `\r\n` and appending `",a\r\n"`.

```
destination.write(line.rstrip("\r\n") + ",a\r\n"))
```

This works even when the file only contains `\n` line endings, so it is robust.

Comment: Or openeing the file as mode `'rU'`